# SterlingDB 2.0 Beta

Tags: sterling-db

I am a complete Sterling newbie so please excuse my question. I have gone to the new GitHub repository and downloaded the latest source code for SterlingDB 2.0 Beta. I am working on a new project that will use Sterling in a Windows 8 Store app, a Windows 8 Phone app and a WPF Desktop app all based on MVVM Light. So using your Test projects in your source code, I understand how the Store and Phone apps use sterling but how does the WPF Desktop use Sterling. Or better yet what dll needs to be referenced in the desktop app. I used the Wintellect.Sterling.Core and Wintellect.Sterling.Server as my references but only because I want the WPF app to use the applications folder. Is this correct for this new version?

By the way Josh, good job...

Orgbrat

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [FileSystemDriver](https://github.com/petermorlion/SterlingDB/blob/master/Wintellect.Sterling.Server/FileSystem/FileSystemDriver.cs) (which is indeed in the Wintellect.Sterling.Server assembly) and specify the path where you want your database to be saved.